# Highlighting values with CSS

Tags: css

I use this CSS code to highlight none empty `<td>`'s:

```
td:not(:empty) {
   background-color: #9ac99d;
}
```

Is there a similar way to highlight values ,lets say, which are greater than 2? I mean without making any changes on the html, without using ids,classes etc.

Comment: no, there is no way with CSS

Comment: ok, thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: The question is similar, yes. and I found a simple jquery solution on the link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41281583/4934426